# How to pass the Interface name to the implementation class Dynamically

Tags: java, osgi

How to pass the Interface name to the implementation class dynamically in osgi?

I need something which logically mean like this:

```
// where the interface name is provided at runtime in Component.xml of declarative sevices in osgi
public class Foo implements <T> {
 // do something
}
```

and so that whatever the Interface name I pass, it should implement that Interface (since the class implements all of the methods of the Interfaces I pass)

Comment: Are you going to provide the implementation for the implemented interface dynamically?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to register services on the fly? Are you after something like [proxies](http://java.dzone.com/articles/power-proxies-java)? OSGi services already allow you to dynamically look up an implementation of a interface, as long as the implementations declare they implement that interface. What extra problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I actually want to develop an Service which will serve any component. for ex: PropertyManagement component should serve the purpose of stationary Management or some books Management or some dvd managemet. if diff components require different services, the same property Component should be able to serve them all such dat we extrnally should not write an adapter for that . the property management component should do it. i just pass the name of the interface and the propertymanagement service should be compatible to provide that service

Comment: You can implement multiple interfaces in that case.

Comment: So if interface T contains method void bar(), what should happen when someone calls bar()?

Answer (score 2):

You can do all kinds of crazy stuff with CGLIB, but *most of the time* you should rethink the way you are doing things and you will likely find a way simpler solution.